# Is the second release from SMbus correct?

Tags: python, smbus

I want to import the SMbus package:
[Link](https://pypi.org/project/smbus/1.1.post2/)

(I use Python 3.7)

I tried running it with my cmd window on win10 and inside Visual Code.
(`pip install smbus`)

- It was possible run install "smbus2" !
  But this package also needs "smbus" :(

I always get this error message:

```
Complete output (5 lines):
running install
   running build
   running build_ext
   building 'i2c' library
   error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```